# Need Query for the below logic to add new column in the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

- if the PersonID contact [TYPE] = "owner" and ends with same [TYPE] = "owner" on the same day for that persinID then output is Y
- An person id first contact will be [TYPE] = "owner" and [TITLE] =
  "Authentication"
- if the personID begin with the [TYPE] = "owner" and ends with some other type on the same day for that persinID then output N
- if the personID doesn't have [TYPE] = "owner" on that particular day then output is  NUll

below is the sample data and Expected output is in Expected result column

Please let me know how to achieve it

I tried but I am not able to get the result as expected

| ID | type | title | date | PersonID | expected results |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3656 | Owner | Authentication | 8/17/2020 | 5538 | N |
| 3688 | Owner | Status | 8/17/2020 | 5538 | N |
| 4536 | Call | Information | 8/17/2020 | 5538 | N |
| 4366 | Owner | Authentication | 8/17/2020 | 6838 | Y |
| 4379 | Owner | Status | 8/17/2020 | 6838 | Y |
| 4554 | Owner | S Status | 8/17/2020 | 6838 | Y |
| 4494 | Owner | Authentication | 9/27/2020 | 3666 | N |
| 4503 | Owner | Status | 9/27/2020 | 3666 | N |
| 4731 | ans | Call | 9/27/2020 | 3666 | N |
| 5030 | ans | Information | 9/27/2020 | 3666 | N |
| 8642 | Owner | Authentication | 9/27/2020 | 3666 | Y |
| 2635 | Owner | Authentication | 9/27/2020 | 5981 | Y |
| 2640 | Owner | Status | 9/27/2020 | 5981 | Y |
| 1234 | tem | private | 10/22/2020 | 9989 | Null |
| 1235 | gap | lagging | 10/22/2020 | 9989 | Null |
| 1236 | loss | loss | 10/22/2020 | 9989 | Null |
| 1237 | call | Status | 10/22/2020 | 9989 | Null |

Comment: "I tried but I am not able to get the result as expected" - so show us what you tried.

Comment: Please explain why `PersonID` `3666` result is not all `Y` but `6838`is all `Y`

Comment: Please also explain rule `3` what does  `Expected results column is available` means

Comment: expected results column is the output i am expecting to see that's column result i need

Comment: @Squirrel
PersonID 3666 begins contacted owner type for Authentication title and end with ans type and again PersonID 3666 begins contacted owner type for Authentication title and end with owner type only on that day so 3666 having 2 Authentication title
but 6838 having only one onwer type and one Authentication title that's y its "Y" for all rows

Comment: If based on your first rule, begin and end with `OWNER` should be a `Y`, so `3666` should be a `Y`. If it is not `Y` that means there are additional rules or conditions that you didn't specified or explained

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions, assuming that ordering is based on `id` -- in particular, `first_value()`.

Your description of the return values is not complete.  But the idea is:

```
select t.*,
       (case when first_type = 'OWNER' and first_type = last_type
             then 'Y'
             when first_type = 'OWNER' and first_title = 'AUTHENTICATION'
             then ?  -- not specified in question
             when first_type = 'OWNER'
             then 'N'
             when sum(case when type = 'OWNER' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by personid, date) = 0
             then NULL
             else ? -- other cases not specified
       end) as expected_results
from (select t.*,
             first_value(type) over (partition by personid, date order by id) as first_type,
             first_value(title) over (partition by personid, date order by id) as first_title,
             first_value(type) over (partition by personid, date order by id desc) as last_type
      from t
     ) t
```

Comment: Tq for the solution